# How to allow PHP outgoing connections only to specific server?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, iptables

On a Red Hat-based host running a fairly recent Apache and PHP 5.2, we are using the [solr-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) library to connect to [an external Solr server](http://websolr.com/). This library requires the PHP directive [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to be enabled. Therefore, I would like to disable outgoing PHP connections via iptables, other than connections to the necessary server.

Googling for an appropriate iptables rule leads down many wrong paths. What rule would allow PHP to connect via CURL or fopen() to a specific server, but no other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about using iptables rule that filters not only based on the destination address/port but also based on the source user?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner uidForYourApacheUser -p tcp --dport 80 -d yourServerIp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner uidForYourApacheUser -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT
```

if needed you can use [su-php](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) to run just your sorl scripts under different uid than your apache.

Comment: Not sure such rule will prevent php form accessing http://script_kiddies_using_url_fopen.com:8080/.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good base to start googling from for further honing.

Comment: @Eric DANNIELOU - su-php with separate config/user just for the lucene part + another user for rest of php and proper file system permissions should sort that out.

Comment: --dport 80 : You wont prevent http access on other ports like 8080

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU there's nothing stopping you from dropping all the tcp traffic and allowing just tcp/80 to lucene machine.

Comment: Yes sounds more secure :)

Answer (score 1):

This can't work. You can not disable PHP connections via iptable. iptables is not aware about which process open a connection.

What you might want to do is to disable all outgoing connection except for one destination IP. But you will break any legitimate outgoing trafic.

Tip : One secure setup could be to install a filtering proxy and to disable all traffic except to the proxy, but that's a lot of work.